# Is there anyway to develop epoll based network programs on mac os x without virtual machine?

Tags: macos, epoll

As I know, epoll is a feature of modern linux kernel. But I hope that there is a way to develop epoll based programs on Mac OS X other than use a virtual machine. Just a development environment is Ok, I'll do load test and run product mode on the real linux server, and of cause the sources will be recompiled on the linux system before these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such; `epoll()` does not exist on Mac OS X. It does have the somewhat-similar [`kqueue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html) system call. Alternatively, you can use a library such as [libevent](http://libevent.org/) that abstracts away the difference.